# Detecting errors from compilation of vhdl files using vcom

Tags: batch-file, modelsim

I'm trying to automate the compilation and simulation of a vhdl project in ModelSim. I'm using batch files and using the `vcom` and `vsim` commands to compile the VHDL files and simulate the testbenches, respectively.

Because it's an automated process I'd like to detect when vcom encounters an error, if one exists, and if one exists copy the command's output into the command window into a text file, for later analysis.

My current workflow looks something like:

```
vcom -work src -2008 ..\..\path\to\file\file_name_1.vhd
vcom -work src -2008 ..\..\path\to\file\file_name_2.vhd
vcom -work src -2008 ..\..\path\to\file\file_name_3.vhd
```

With each vcom command leading to the expected output (or similar). Ending with the number of Errors/Warnings:

```
-- Loading package STANDARD
-- Loading package TEXTIO
-- Loading package std_logic_1164
-- Loading package NUMERIC_STD
-- Compiling entity file_name
-- Compiling architecture sim of file_name
End time: 10:09:01 on Aug 14,2018, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
```

However in the case that there is an error, is there a condition or flag raised by vcom to see that an error has been raised?

How would one ensure that when an error is raised the output of the vcom command, that led to the error, in the command window is logged into a separate text file?

---

I've been using these docs for the [Command Reference Manual](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/136364-modelsim-me-10-4c-command-reference-manual-for-libero-soc-v11-7) (even though I am using ModelSim PE 10.7). I've seen the `-error` option for vcom, although it doesn't seem applicable in this case.

Comment: See your program's `exit` command. If batch use `If errorlevel 1` to detect.